# Excel Macros file size

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with macros. The actual file is 6MB and when a `Save Macro` runs the file is saved but its size is around 32MB and don't contain any macros.

I don't know why the saved file size is larger than the actual file size.

**Save Macro**

```
Sub SaveSummaries()
    '
    ' SaveSummaries Macro
    '
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Sheets(Array("Donor Totals", "GDBA", "DT", "CLIC", "GOSH")).Select
    Sheets("Donor Totals").Activate
    Sheets(Array("Donor Totals", "GDBA", "DT", "CLIC", "GOSH")).Copy
    ChDir "C:\Users\Chandra.Cherukuri\Desktop\Area Donor Summaries"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Chandra.Cherukuri\Desktop\Area Donor Summaries\Donor Summary_All Charities.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Sheets("Area Summaries").Select

End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Save Macro is Saving data from Main file which is 6MB

Comment: Check for "blank" rows.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Chandra.Cherukuri\Desktop\Area Donor Summaries\Donor Summary_All Charities.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

where you specify the format as **xlOpenXMLWorkbook**. In this file format you cannot store macros and it is an XML file - which basically means a text file with a lot of overhead (tags).

If you want to save the workbook with macros in Open XML format you can use: **xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled** option, but it will crate a large file. In my opinion either **xlExcel12** (binary file with macros, *.xslb) or **xlExcel8** (standard Excel file till version 2003) are better options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in Saved file there are no macros, what is the best format to save files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have changed the file format to xlExcel8. Saved file is around 5.6Mb. but the previous saved files are around 147KB. There are no macros in the saved file, it just copy data from one sheet and paste and save it in new sheet.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that saving in XML and binary file produces a file of the same size? Impossible.

Comment: You can try to clear unused styles: http://tjshome.com/blog/238/guide/excel/accounting

Comment: I am not saying saving in XML and Binary file produces a file of same size. Actual file size is 6mb including macros, after saving it in xlExcel8 format file size reduced to 5.6mb, file sizes which are saved before are only 147kb. There are no macros in saved file.