# My macro makes the file size larger although it deletes information

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro to create individual reports for different stakeholders in the company. The problem is that the files saved by the macro are larger than the parent files.
Please mind:

- There are no "Empty lines" taking up space.
- There are no connections to external sources in the outcome files.
- There is no macro in any file (original or outcome).
- I did see a very similar post from a couple of years ago but this had no satisfying answer. Although someone hinted at the command used to save, this is the one I use :
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\path\" & WR_Date & "*Monthly-Report*" & Partner & ".xlsx "

([Excel Macros file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348628/excel-macros-file-size))

Below is a recap of the steps done by the macro.

1. Macro opens "Master workbook"
2. Deletes all external connections (OLAP)
3. Deletes calculations in the tables (copy as simple values)
4. Deletes reconciliation table sheets
5. Saves 4 files (Division master, Country master, Territory master, Partner master).
6. Uses these master files to delete all irrelevant data for the stakeholder.
7. Update all pivot caches (settings of all pivotes to not keep memory anyway.
8. Protects all worksheets and the workbook.
9. Saves the files with the correct names.

As per the discussion in below comments, I am pasting my macro below. The replace all function was used to remove any kind of sensitive information, sometimes the result may be weirs but it should definitely be enough to spot the issue.

I am pretty sure that the macro is causing this: if I replicate the steps done by the macro the size of the files is much smaller (5-15 Mo vs 50-60 Mo).

Also, the territory reports are normal sized. The country and division files are bigger than their master file, the partner files are also too big.

EDIT:
After plenty of checks, I have found the begining of an answer, it seems to be related to the way the pivot tables are refreshed. My code was going like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
For Each pc In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
    pc.Refresh
Next pc
```

I have now removed the "Refresh all" prior to refreshing the pivot cache and save about 20 Mo per Division and Country file. This is still not entirely satisfactory since the division and country files still are around the same size as their parent or bigger but these reports need to be posted today.

I'll keep on looking but will definitely try to poste you a full resolution by next month!

Comment: If you want to save space, try saving the file as `.xlsb`

Comment: Will this format support all the pivot tables and slicers?
The "executive master" created in the 5th step is about 30 Mo in size, the files that the macro creates from this master are 55 Mo...

Comment: Yes, it does. :)

Comment: Thank you, will try this :)

Comment: Sadly did not even save 1kb :(

Comment: You can check if there are excess formatting, review this --> https://support.office.com/en-us/article/clean-excess-cell-formatting-on-a-worksheet-e744c248-6925-4e77-9d49-4874f7474738. Also, if you are using pivottables, here are some space saving ideas --> http://nhsexcel.com/massive-excel-spreadsheets-how-to-reduce-the-size-of-pivot-table-workbooks/. Keep in mind, without the actual spreadsheet, it's hard to know for sure what's up.

Comment: I know that it is hard to spot the issue without the file, this contains way too much sensitive information though.
Also, I am pretty sure that it has something to do with my macro, as if I o the same manually, the resulting files are ranging between 5 and 15 Mo. I am editing my initial request to attach my macro, I've replaced all sensitive information of this macro to share with you.

Comment: There is something obvious missing in this question.... The code!

Answer (score 1):

Ran a quick test and it may be related to the data in the file being corrupted.

- "TestSize1" files are only containing data values
- "TestSize2" files are only containing of excel functions
- "TestSize3" files are only containing of formatting

[Windows File Explorer - Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUEPG.png)

I am only seeing a minor increase in file size on the "Values only" or "TestSize1" workbook.  I do believe you shouldn't see a size increase unless the data in the workbook is corrupted for your case.  This file type just permits the additional save of features, such as Macros/VBA code.

["The first is the default XLSX, then there's XLSM which is identical to XLSX except it can contain macros..."](http://www.excel4business.com/excel-blog/articles/2012/12/04/xlsb-as-an-alternative-to-xlsx-xlsm.html)

I would look into copying just the data values out into a New workbook and save that as `.xlsb`. It should reduce the size (obviously), but also it removes features that excel maybe misreading or corrupted.  After that open the `.xlsb` in a restarted window of excel (maybe restart your computer before as well to clear cache) and attempt saving back to whatever format you prefer. Add function and formatting to restore the document.

This has worked for me, off and on, for recovering large `.csv` files.  I hope it works for you.

Comment: There is no corrupted data in the files, I did plenty of checks.